# Derivatives of Volume Integral and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My question is regarding the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and if it applies to a volume integral. I will try to present the problem but I am a bit rusty on my calculus.

The given situation I have is a volume integral of a multivariable function $ F = F(x,y,z,t) $
which is equal to zero:

$$ \int [F(x,y,z,t) ]\ dV = 0$$

$ F(x,y,z,t) $ is a scalar function describing temperature and heat - I can go into more details if that is relevant but the function is not fully defined (it is unknown).

To solve for $ F $ I would like to take the derivatives. I am not sure if the following steps are valid!

First, write explicitly the volume integral:

$$ \iiint[F(x,y,z,t)]\ dxdydz = 0$$

Take the derivatives:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \Big( \iiint[F(x,y,z,t)]\  dxdydz \Big) = 0 $$

Then, apply fundamental theorem one by one (beginning from the inside $ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int \big[F(x,y,z,t)]\ dz = F(x,y,z,t)\  $) until you get the result:

$$ F(x,y,z,t) = 0 $$

Is this allowed? In my research I read that the multivariable "analog" to the Fundamental Theorem is Stokes Theorem, but I do not see how that is relevant in this situation. Again my calculus is rusty and it was never good to begin with so I hope this isn't something appears in the first result of a google search (I googled!).

As a test to verify I took a couple random multivariable functions, integrated them over $x$, $y$ and $z$ then then took the the derivatives and I did indeed return the integrand. I did this on wolfram alpha. I would like to know if this is a general principle that I just don't know the name of (Multivariable FT of $C$?) or if there is a mistake in my work.

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not work that way.

The fundamental theorem works for an integral with variable bounds, hence a function of the bounds values. You just have a constant $V$.

Now think of a function $F$ that is anything positive in half of the domain, and the opposite in the rest of the domain: $V=0$, but $F\ne 0$.